# How to make sure a TCP socket connects at creation time

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, tcpsocket

I have a client application that sends TCP packets. Currently, my application does this: 
creates a socket, binds and sends the packets.

```
struct sockaddr_in localaddress;
localaddress.sin_port = htons(0);
localaddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

int socket;
socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0));
bind(socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) );
```

And in another thread, the application connects and sends the packets:

```
struct socketaddr_in remoteaddress;
// omitted: code to set the remote address/ port etc...
nRet = connect (socket, (struct sockaddr * ) & remoteaddress, sizeof (sockaddr_in ));
if (nRet == -1)
    nRet = WSAGetLastError();
if (nRet == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
    int errorCode = 0;
    socklen_t codeLen = sizeof(int);
    int retVal = getsockopt(
            socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, ( char * ) &errorCode, &codeLen );
    if (errorCode == 0 && retVal != 0)
        errorCode = errno;
}
/* if the connect succeeds, program calls a callback function to notify the socket is connected, which then calls send() */
```

Now I want to specify a port range for local port, so I changed the code to

```
nPortNumber = nPortLow;
localaddress.sin_port = htons(nPortNumber);
```

and loops nPortNumber in my port range, e.g ( 4000 - 5000 ) until the bind succeeds.

Since I always start my nPortNumber from the low port, if a socket is previously created on the same port, I get the WSAEADDRINUSE error as errorCode, which is too late for me because it has already passed the socket creation stage. (Why didn't I get WSAEADDRINUSE at bind() or connect()?)

Is there a way I can get the WSAEADDRINUSE earlier or is there a way to create a socket in the port range that binds and connects?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your application needs you to control the source port?  Also, are you actually setting the remote address to connect to and you just omitted that from your code for brevity?

Comment: @evil-otto , My application needs to control the source port to be in the port range. Yes, I'm setting the remote address.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer with 100% certainty as for that I should know at which point you actually get `WSAEADDRINUSE`.

IN any case, it is normal you don't get it at bind, because you use `INADDR_ANY`. IIRC, this actually delays the bind process to the actual connect (my guess is it then changes the INADDR based on routing for the remote addr). However, as far as I know, you should then actually get the error at the call of connect...

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. But connect() just returns WSAEWOULDBLOCK.